# How to override all setters of the fields with custom annotation?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

Some fields of some classes in my Spring Boot project are annotated with my custom annotation.

How can I tell Spring to override all setter methods of those annotated fields, so that, when setter of those fields are called, it will set that field to "" or null?

I dont want to go around and change my classes, because there is a lot of them.
I just want to code all needed logic on one place.

Consider that I have, for example, 100 classes and that I dont know their names, I just know that they have some fields with custom annotation, meaning I need some generic solution.

Comment: If this is a custom annotation of your making, a better solution may be to generate the setter automatically with an annotation processor.

Comment: @AlvinThompson It doesn't matter whether it's his own annotation or not.

Comment: @LukasKörfer: My point was if the OP has the knowledge to create a custom annotation, than they may have the knowledge needed to create an annotation processor. In any case, that's not relevant to the point that an annotation processor may be a better way to go.

Comment: In pure Spring, assuming that you cannot run a compile time annotation processor, simply use an [`@Around` advice](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/).

Comment: can you be sure that all the method does is set the value? will the users of these methods know this is the behavior? will that break stuff that is already using these? you don't know the classes. Use search. changing 100's of behaviors that you don't even know what is being changed is bad. plus 100 isn't that big a number. maybe you can write a regex and find replace.

Comment: Thank you guys for all suggestions! It looks like an @Around will do the work :)
I dont want to use regex and find replace because I am creating a library. When someone adds this library to the project next step is to set annotations on some fields in the classes in the project. In my library I am catching all requests that users send, when they are using that project, that has added my library.  Together with requests, I am also catching the responses and I dont want those responses to have those fields that are  annotated, just to have "" or null instead of those fields :)